# jQuery Add / Remove Class on Click

Tags: jquery, onclick, addclass

```
function NavMenu() {
    $(function() {                       
      $(".toggle-topbar").click(function() {
        $(".top-bar").addClass("expanded"); 
      });
    });
}
```

This function allows a Menu Button to expand a drop down for when running on a mobile/tablet device, ive so far got it this far, which expands the drop down, however how do i go about removing the class when i then click the option again?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass)

```
$(".top-bar").toggleClass("expanded");
```